How can I rank after filtering inside a window function?
I have a huge BigQuery table "taskperformance" that attributes tasks to sales (ordered in this example for easier
understanding):



sale_id
sale_timestamp
task_id
task_timestamp
is_same_store
is_retail_task




S123
2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC
T1
2024-01-05 09:00:00 UTC
TRUE
TRUE


S123
2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC
T2
2024-01-04 10:00:00 UTC
FALSE
FALSE


S123
2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC
T3
2024-01-03 14:00:00 UTC
TRUE
FALSE


S123
2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC
T4
2024-01-02 16:00:00 UTC
TRUE
TRUE


S456
2024-02-15 09:30:00 UTC
T5
2024-02-14 15:00:00 UTC
TRUE
FALSE


S456
2024-02-15 09:30:00 UTC
T6
2024-02-13 12:00:00 UTC
FALSE
TRUE


S456
2024-02-15 09:30:00 UTC
T7
2024-02-12 11:00:00 UTC
TRUE
TRUE



I would like to add two columns to this table:

same_store_rank: where I rank, for each sale, the tasks with is_same_store = TRUE, ordered by task_timestamp
descending. When is_same_store = FALSE, the rank is NULL.
retail_task_rank: where I rank, for each sale, the tasks with is_retail_task = TRUE, ordered by task_timestamp
descending. When is_retail_task = FALSE, the rank is NULL.

So I want to obtain this:



sale_id
sale_timestamp
task_id
task_timestamp
is_same_store
is_retail_task
same_store_rank
retail_task_rank




S123
2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC
T1
2024-01-05 09:00:00 UTC
true
true
1
1


S123
2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC
T2
2024-01-04 10:00:00 UTC
false
false
NULL
NULL


S123
2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC
T3
2024-01-03 14:00:00 UTC
true
false
2
NULL


S123
2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC
T4
2024-01-02 16:00:00 UTC
true
true
3
2


S456
2024-02-15 09:30:00 UTC
T5
2024-02-14 15:00:00 UTC
true
false
1
NULL


S456
2024-02-15 09:30:00 UTC
T6
2024-02-13 12:00:00 UTC
false
true
NULL
1


S456
2024-02-15 09:30:00 UTC
T7
2024-02-12 11:00:00 UTC
true
true
2
2



But I can't seem to find a way to filter on a condition inside a window function before applying the RANK().
When I try it, the rank is still incremented for rows where the condition is false:
WITH taskperformance AS (
SELECT 'S123' AS sale_id, TIMESTAMP('2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC') AS sale_timestamp, 'T1' AS task_id, TIMESTAMP('2024-01-05 09:00:00 UTC') AS task_timestamp, TRUE AS is_same_store, TRUE AS is_retail_task
UNION ALL
SELECT 'S123', TIMESTAMP('2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC'), 'T2', TIMESTAMP('2024-01-04 10:00:00 UTC'), FALSE, FALSE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'S123', TIMESTAMP('2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC'), 'T3', TIMESTAMP('2024-01-03 14:00:00 UTC'), TRUE, FALSE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'S123', TIMESTAMP('2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC'), 'T4', TIMESTAMP('2024-01-02 16:00:00 UTC'), TRUE, TRUE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'S456', TIMESTAMP('2024-02-15 09:30:00 UTC'), 'T5', TIMESTAMP('2024-02-14 15:00:00 UTC'), TRUE, FALSE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'S456', TIMESTAMP('2024-02-15 09:30:00 UTC'), 'T6', TIMESTAMP('2024-02-13 12:00:00 UTC'), FALSE, TRUE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'S456', TIMESTAMP('2024-02-15 09:30:00 UTC'), 'T7', TIMESTAMP('2024-02-12 11:00:00 UTC'), TRUE, TRUE
)
SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN is_same_store THEN
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sale_id ORDER BY task_timestamp DESC)
    END AS same_store_rank,
    CASE WHEN is_retail_task THEN
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sale_id ORDER BY task_timestamp DESC)
    END AS retail_task_rank
FROM taskperformance
ORDER BY task_id




sale_id
sale_timestamp
task_id
task_timestamp
is_same_store
is_retail_task
same_store_rank
retail_task_rank




S123
2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC
T1
2024-01-05 09:00:00 UTC
true
true
1
1


S123
2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC
T2
2024-01-04 10:00:00 UTC
false
false
NULL
NULL


S123
2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC
T3
2024-01-03 14:00:00 UTC
true
false
3
NULL


S123
2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC
T4
2024-01-02 16:00:00 UTC
true
true
4
4


S456
2024-02-15 09:30:00 UTC
T5
2024-02-14 15:00:00 UTC
true
false
1
NULL


S456
2024-02-15 09:30:00 UTC
T6
2024-02-13 12:00:00 UTC
false
true
NULL
2


S456
2024-02-15 09:30:00 UTC
T7
2024-02-12 11:00:00 UTC
true
true
3
3



For example, for same_store_rank, I get [1, NULL, 3, 4] instead of [1, NULL, 2, 3]
I think this could be done using CTEs and WHERE clauses, and then joining on the taskperformance table, but this seems
wasteful to read the table 3 times:
WITH
    taskperformance AS (
        SELECT 'S123' AS sale_id, TIMESTAMP('2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC') AS sale_timestamp, 'T1' AS task_id, TIMESTAMP('2024-01-05 09:00:00 UTC') AS task_timestamp, TRUE AS is_same_store, TRUE AS is_retail_task
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'S123', TIMESTAMP('2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC'), 'T2', TIMESTAMP('2024-01-04 10:00:00 UTC'), FALSE, FALSE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'S123', TIMESTAMP('2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC'), 'T3', TIMESTAMP('2024-01-03 14:00:00 UTC'), TRUE, FALSE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'S123', TIMESTAMP('2024-01-06 10:00:00 UTC'), 'T4', TIMESTAMP('2024-01-02 16:00:00 UTC'), TRUE, TRUE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'S456', TIMESTAMP('2024-02-15 09:30:00 UTC'), 'T5', TIMESTAMP('2024-02-14 15:00:00 UTC'), TRUE, FALSE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'S456', TIMESTAMP('2024-02-15 09:30:00 UTC'), 'T6', TIMESTAMP('2024-02-13 12:00:00 UTC'), FALSE, TRUE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'S456', TIMESTAMP('2024-02-15 09:30:00 UTC'), 'T7', TIMESTAMP('2024-02-12 11:00:00 UTC'), TRUE, TRUE
    ),
    same_store_ranks AS (
        SELECT sale_id, task_id, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sale_id ORDER BY task_timestamp DESC) AS same_store_rank
        FROM taskperformance
        WHERE is_same_store
    ),
    retail_task_ranks AS (
        SELECT sale_id, task_id, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sale_id ORDER BY task_timestamp DESC) AS retail_task_rank
        FROM taskperformance
        WHERE is_retail_task
    )

SELECT *
FROM taskperformance
LEFT JOIN same_store_ranks
USING(sale_id, task_id)
LEFT JOIN retail_task_ranks
USING(sale_id, task_id)
ORDER BY task_id

Doing this, I get the expected result, but I'd like to avoid reading taskperformance multiple times and then having to
JOIN, because the code is verbose, and I think reading the huge taskperformance table multiple times is not good for
performance. Especially since I have other rank columns to add, not just the two in this example.

You can partition by columns in question to get continuous ranks
SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN is_same_store THEN
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sale_id, is_same_store ORDER BY task_timestamp DESC)
    END AS same_store_rank,
    CASE WHEN is_retail_task THEN
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sale_id, is_retail_task ORDER BY task_timestamp DESC)
    END AS retail_task_rank
FROM taskperformance
ORDER BY task_id


Interesting approach. I'm waiting to see if there is another answer that does not force me to specify the is_same_store/is_retail_task condition twice. Because in this example the condition is simple, but in my project it is actually a lot more complex.
Also, I was hoping for an answer that would always reuse the "same" window, thinking it would somehow improve performance? Because here we are creating different windows for each rank, and I wonder if it's less performant.
